# How to check the Docker Desktop installed version?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm having Docker Desktop on my Windows PC. While checking the version of the docker in the registry it shows the version as `2.1.0.5`. But when I running the below command in the Windows CMD, it returns the version as `19.03.5`.

Which one is the correct version and why it's showing two different versions for a single application?

Comment: what below command? This is very unclear.

Comment: `2.1.0.5` is possibly referring to docker desktop application's version not docker itself.

Comment: The registry version is of Docker Desktop app while the version number you get in CMD is docker engine version (assuming you used docker -v in CMD)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two version numbers:

- Docker Desktop for Windows ([*Release Notes*](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/))
- Docker Engine ([*Release Notes*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/))

You can get the version number of Docker Engine with [`docker version`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/version/) command:

```
docker version
```

To get the Docker Desktop for Windows version number you have to look at the registry. Also have a look at this thread on the Docker forum to get this value: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-check-docker-version/76677.

**You are using the following versions:**

- [Docker Desktop for Windows 2.1.0.5](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2105)
- [Docker Engine 19.03.5](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#19035)

Answer (score 12):

On windows, you can check this registry entry:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Docker Desktop
```

But probably a lot easier if you right click on the windows icon in the lower left corner,  pick `Apps and Features` and click `Docker Desktop` in the list on the right hand side of the new window. You will see a version number like `2.2.0.3` or similar. This is the version of Docker Desktop.

The other two version numbers that the `docker version` command prints for you, they are the version number of the `Docker Engine Server` and `Docker Engine Client`.

Comment: As you said the easiest way is to type "Apps and Features" in windows search and search the list by typing docker in search box and selecting the docker app.

Answer (score 6):

It's also visible in the **About Docker Desktop** box that can be found via right clicking the whale in the system tray and select "About Docker Desktop" menu item

Comment: Wow. This is the best way in my opinion. It gives you the version not only of desktop but also engine etc.

Answer (score 3):

check under Apps & Features in windows. type docker and click on it.

Comment: no longer seems to work, but you can see the version when going to uninstall

Comment: i will check it later this day

Answer (score 2):

Just in case the link in the answer dies, here's the one liner from the Docker forums to get the version in Powershell:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | select DisplayName,DisplayVersion | where {$_.DisplayName -like "Docker*"}
```

This will result in an output similar to this:

```
DisplayName    DisplayVersion
-----------    --------------
Docker Desktop 3.2.2
```

Or, if you just want the version string:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | where {$_.DisplayName -like "Docker*"} | select -ExpandProperty DisplayVersion
```

Output:

```
3.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10:

- Go to Settings -> Apps & Features
- click on the Docker-App
- click on "Uninstall" - version-number of Docker Desktop is displayed

Answer (score 0):

`Windows settings` -> `Apps` -> Select the Docker Desktop

it will show you the program version

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, I had an issue where the Docker Desktop -> About dialogue box would just not show up. I found that the Docker Desktop version is also displayed under Preferences -> Software updates. I presume something similar can be found in the Windows version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Docker Desktop version is shown bottom right in the running Docker Desktop application window. This is on Windows 11 as of v4.21.1 of docker desktop.

When the mouse cursor is hovered over the version info text I get an extra tooltip stating "Your application is up-to date".

For more complete version info see the accepted answer by Sebastian Brosch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168253/987631)